# Is there a online/offline tool to convert the values of given numbers in proportion and in percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example

There should be field for 2 values

**31 X 12**

now if change **31** to **30** then second field should change accordingly

and 2nd functionality should give values in **%**

so if **31 X 12**

and if put **50%** in another field and press submit it should give the **50%** of **31 X 12** > **15.5 X 6**

I given above values just for example to explain. Actually values can be any number.

Comment: "accordingly" - does that mean from 12 to 11 for the second field?

Comment: @pimvdb yes u r right. or vice versa. if we put 11 in 2md field then 1st field should change accordingly

Comment: @WebDev - Offline free tool is also ok. This type of functionality comes in may image editors but i wanted to know if there is any separate and less time taking utility for this.

Comment: Every decent graphics/image tool I've used (including free ones like Gimp and Inkscape) have this functionality built in. It would also be trivial to implement.

Comment: @Pointy I know that but we always don't work with images. some time we need to resize the elements on page by using css or js

Answer (score 1):

See following using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/YGUcy/

http://jsfiddle.net/YGUcy/1/

Comment: 2nd tool is fine but first is not